# Inserting a premade slide layout from excel into a presentation

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to create a PowerPoint presentation using excel macros in VBA from a list of data. I've been able to make the slide show from the table that houses the data. Now what I'm trying to do is create a custom layout for the slideshow that the data will then be put in.

I've made two slides in an excel sheet that I want to use, one is the cover sheet that I want at the beginning of the presentation and the other is a blank sheet that contains an image at the bottom of it, which contains information about the presentation. When the slide show is created I want all of the slides with the data to be put onto the blank sheet with the image. Is there a simple way to do this using the code Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutObject)and then specifying which object from the sheet that I want to use. Also does the slide that I created need to be a micro-enabled slide or some other object type. If someone could provide some example code to work off or some other source on this info that be awesome. Also let me know if I can provide anymore detail on this topic. Thanks,

[image: Object type image:]

Comment: Rather than trying to create slide layouts in Excel, create them in PowerPoint, then use that PowerPoint file to create new slides from the layout. Use Excel only as a data source, not a formatting source.

Comment: I would then have to reference those PowerPoints correct, 1 for the title slide and another for every other slide. Or can I do it on one slide show and reference each slide individually? Also what's the point of being able to create slides in excel if you can reference them easily in a macro? Thanks for your response.

Comment: One PowerPoint file can hold all your layouts and you can call any of them from Excel. I don't understand your second question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to just copy the range of the slides that I created in the excel sheet and then paste them into the slide that I wanted using VBA code. There was no point in creating a whole new presentation to reference when I could just make the slides in the excel page its self.